# PyCharm debugging: Variable Inspection, how to see more values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pycharm

I am dealing with rather large arrays and when I debug, I need to inspect them.
The problem is though that PyCharm only shows a minority of all values within the array.
For instance, if I debug my code, the following is shown in the "Variables" window for a large *numpy* array of boolean values:

```
[ True  True  True ...,  True  True  True]
```

Even right click on the variable and choosing "Inspect..." would just open a new window showing the exact same shortened array.

How can I get rid of the `...` in the middle, or at least extend the display to more than only the first and last three entries?

Comment: Not sure if PyCharm overrides the settings but try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/print-the-full-numpy-array

Comment: Nope, doesn't, thanks!