# Pandas to_csv always substitute long numpy.ndarray with ellipsis

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm confronted with a nauseating issue dealing with the to_csv() function for DataFrame in pandas 0.14.0. I have a list of long numpy arrays as one column in the DataFrame df:

```
>>> df['col'][0]    
array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 9993, 9994, 9995])
>>> len(df['col'][0])
46889
>>> type(df['col'][0][0])
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

If I save df by

```
df.to_csv('df.csv')
```

and open df.csv in LibreOffice, the corresponding column shows up like this:

```
[ 0,    1,    2, ..., 9993, 9994, 9995]
```

rather than listing all the 46889 numbers. I'm wondering if there's an approach that can force to_csv to list all numbers rather than showing up ellipsis?

df.info()

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 4 columns):
pair          2 non-null object
ARXscore      2 non-null float64
bselect       2 non-null bool
col           2 non-null object
dtypes: bool(1), float64(1), object(2)
```

Comment: What does the output of `df.info()` look like? The pasted output with spacing in the array entries like that seems odd.

Comment: Adding comment here is not well-formated so I revised the question to include df.info()

Comment: This is kind of an odd way to store the data, why is the numpy array being used as an object?

Comment: You're storing the array as a string so the output you are seeing is expected. If you want to out put an array you need to get that actual array not a truncated string of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some sense this is a duplicate of [printing the entire numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1988024/1240268), since to_csv simply asks each item in your DataFrame for it's `__str__`, so you need to see how that prints:

```
In [11]: np.arange(10000)
Out[11]: array([   0,    1,    2, ..., 9997, 9998, 9999])

In [12]: np.arange(10000).__str__()
Out[12]: '[   0    1    2 ..., 9997 9998 9999]'
```

as you can see when it's over a certain threshold it prints with ellipsis, set it to NaN:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
```

To give an example:

```
In [21]: df = pd.DataFrame([[np.arange(10000)]])

In [22]: df  # Note: pandas printing is different!!
Out[22]:
                                                   0
0  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,...

In [23]: s = StringIO()

In [24]: df.to_csv(s)

In [25]: s.getvalue()  # ellipsis
Out[25]: ',0\n0,"[   0    1    2 ..., 9997 9998 9999]"\n'
```

Once changed `to_csv` records the entire array:

```
In [26]: np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')

In [27]: s = StringIO()

In [28]: df.to_csv(s)

In [29]: s.getvalue()  # no ellipsis (it's all there)
Out[29]: ',0\n0,"[   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14\n   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29\n   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44\n   45   46   47   48   49   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59\n   60   61  # the whole thing is here...
```

*As mentioned this is not usually a good choice of structure for a DataFrame (numpy arrays in object columns) as you lose much of the pandas speed/efficiency/magic sauce.*

Comment: This works for the numpy print options, but my pandas df still creates fixed ellipsis

Answer (score 2):

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
```

works not with the latest version.
Use:

```
import sys
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```