# Calculating distance between two elements only in the array in python

Tags: python, arrays, distance, euclidean-distance

So I have two questions: First I'm trying to print my array that contains 1004 elements but it's printing only the first 29 elements and then jumping to 974 to continue printing. How can I get the full array of 1004 elements?

This is my code

```
paired_data = []
for x in data:
    closest, ignored = pairwise_distances_argmin_min(x, result)
    paired_data.append([x, result[closest]])
#print paired_data
S = pd.DataFrame(paired_data, columns=['x','center'])
print S
# distance
Y = pdist(S, 'euclidean')
print Y
```

Also I want to calculate the distance between each two elements of the array. for example

0                [5, 4]           [3, 2]

1               [22, -10]  [78, 90]

I want to calculate the distance( Euclidean ) between [5, 4]  and [3, 2] and so on for all the rest of the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To keep things from getting confusing, can you please edit your question so it only has one question in it, then ask another question for your second question?

Comment: I can't ask two questions in the same day.. Sorry !

Comment: Oh dang, I didn't realize that was a restriction! Well, check out this answer which addresses your first question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/print-the-full-numpy-array

Comment: have you tried `from scipy.spatial import distance`

Comment: you might also find http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html helpful

Comment: I will search for from scipy.spatial import distance example. if you have one already, I would appreciate it

Comment: I edited my code calculating the distance with from scipy.spatial import distance , but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution to #1:

```
print(S.to_string())    # print the entire table
```

and to get distances

```
# assumes Python 3
from functools import partial

def dist(row, col1, col2):
    return sum((c2 - c1)**2 for c1,c2 in zip(row[col1], row[col2])) ** 0.5

# compose a function (name the columns it applies to)
s_dist = partial(dist, col1="x", col2="center")
# apply it
S["dist"] = S.apply(s_dist, axis=1)
```

Comment: @Micheal: I think it should work as is, but I do not have anything but 3.4 on this machine to test with.

Comment: If I want to square ( ^2) each of these distances (1004 distances values), and then sum all of them after do the square, how can I do that?

Comment: @Micheal: it is an n-dimensional Euclidean distance. If you want sum of squares, try `sq_sum = (S["dist"]**2).sum()`.

Comment: so why you multiply it by ** 0.5?

Comment: `**` is exponentiation, not multiplication, so `x ** 0.5` is square root of x.

Comment: why I'm getting this error: when running the distance code above: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1

Comment: @Micheal:  Without seeing your exact code, it's hard to tell but at a guess you've changed the `s_dist = partial` line (which takes a 3-argument function and returns a one-argument function) and then tried to pass it two arguments.