# Python Word Frequencies with pre-defined words

Tags: python, python-3.x, word-count, word-frequency

I have a set of data in a text file and i would like to build a frequency table based on pre-defined words(drive,street,i,lives). below is the example

```
 ID |  Text
 ---|--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | i drive to work everyday in the morning and i drive back in the evening on main street
 2  | i drive back in a car and then drive to the gym on 5th street
 3  | Joe lives in Newyork on NY street
 4  | Tod lives in Jersey city on NJ street
```

Here i what i would like to get as output

```
ID  |  drive |  street  |   i  |  lives
----|--------|----------|------|-------
1   |   2    |    1     |   2  |   0
2   |   2    |    1     |   1  |   0
3   |   0    |    1     |   0  |   1
4   |   0    |    1     |   0  |   1
```

Here is my code that i'm using and i can find the number of words but this does not solve the need for me and i would like to use a set of pre-defined words to find the counts as shown above

```
   from nltk.corpus import stopwords
   import string
   from collections import Counter
   import nltk
   from nltk.tag import pos_tag

   xy = open('C:\Python\data\file.txt').read().split()
   q = (w.lower() for w in xy)

   stopset = set(stopwords.words('english'))

   filtered_words = [word for word in xyz if not word  in stopset]
   filtered_words = []
   for word in xyz:
       if word not in stopset:
       filtered_words.append(word)
   print(Counter(filtered_words))
   print(len(filtered_words))
```

Comment: Why do you have both a list comprehension and then the manual version straight after?

Comment: What output does the code produce?

Comment: Counter({'street': 4, 'drive': 4, 'back': 2, 'lives': 2, 'main': 1, 'morning': 1, 'nj': 1, '5th': 1, 'tod': 1, 'everyday': 1, 'newyork': 1, 'jersey': 1, 'joe': 1, 'city': 1, 'gym': 1, 'ny': 1, 'car': 1, 'evening': 1, 'work': 1})

Comment: @AlexHall - did not get what you meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer` seems to be close to what you're looking for. Also, `collections.Counter` might be helpful. How are you planning to use this data structure? If you're trying to doing machine learning/prediction, by chance, then it's worthwhile to look into the different vectorizers in `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`.

Edit:

```
text = ['i drive to work everyday in the morning and i drive back in the evening on main street',
        'i drive back in a car and then drive to the gym on 5th street',
        'Joe lives in Newyork on NY street',
        'Tod lives in Jersey city on NJ street']

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vocab = ['drive', 'street', 'i', 'lives']

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = vocab)

# turn the text above into a matrix of shape R X C
# where R is number of rows (elements in your text array)
# and C is the number of elements in the set of all words in your text array
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(text)

# sparse to dense matrix
X = X.toarray()

# get the feature names from the already-fitted vectorizer
vectorizer_feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# prove that the vectorizer's feature names are identical to the vocab you specified above
assert vectorizer_feature_names == vocab

# make a table with word frequencies as values and vocab as columns
out_df = pd.DataFrame(data = X, columns = vectorizer_feature_names)

print(out_df)
```

And, your result:

```
       drive  street  i  lives
    0      2       1  0      0
    1      2       1  0      0
    2      0       1  0      1
    3      0       1  0      1
```

Comment: i'm not sure if i can use predefined words to find the frequency using sklearn.feature_extraction.text. i presently would need to find the frequency only for certain words

Comment: Worked up perfect and thanks for sharing as i did not know how to use pre-defined words in CountVectorizer . Also, there is another newbie doubt that i have - i have made some changes to the above code(remove stopwords,punctuations etc..) and tried to run on a file with 2000 records and when i output to a text file or output using PyCharm, i see few records and then see bunch of blank line ............... and then see last few lines. How can i correct this ?

Comment: If you're talking about the matrix `X`, `numpy` limits how much of an array is printed to save your console from printing thousands and thousands of rows' worth of data. Your data is there; it's just not displayed in that view. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/print-the-full-numpy-array) is something worth reading if you're interested in print the full matrix (although with 2000 records, I wouldn't recommend it!).

Answer (score 0):

Simply ask for the words you want instead of the stop words you don't want:

```
filtered_words = [word for word in xyz if word in ['drive', 'street', 'i', 'lives']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the amount of a certain word in a list, you can use `list.count(word)` to find that, so if you have a list of words you want to get frequencies of, you can do something like this:

```
wanted_words = ["drive", "street", "i", "lives"]
frequencies = [xy.count(i) for i in wanted_words]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alex Halls idea to pre-filter - afterwards just use `defaultdict`. It's really comfortable to use for counting.

```
from collections import defaultdict
s = 'i drive to work everyday in the morning and i drive back in the evening on main street'
filtered_words = [word for word in s.split() 
                  if word in ['drive', 'street', 'i', 'lives']]
d = defaultdict(int)
for k in filtered_words: 
    d[k] += 1
print(d)
```