# Print all rows in the table

Tags: python, row

`stat_data` list has 323 items which I want to print to console:

```
from astropy.table import Table, Column
t = Table(rows=stat_data, names=('Redacted Term', 'Length', 'File', 'Type'))
print(t)
```

It's not printing all rows. Help me print all rows:

```
Redacted Term Length             File              Type
------------- ------ ---------------------------- ------
Trump      5                       1.html  names
4909090909     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
3235294117     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
5957446808     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
8518518518     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
3255813953     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
5227272727     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
3076923076     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
0555555555     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
5384615384     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
4210526315     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
7777777777     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
3181818181     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
5869565217     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
1153846153     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
4347826086     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
2043010752     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
8260869565     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
6315789473     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
4583333333     10 otherfiles/sample-output.txt phones
  ...    ...                          ...    ...
William      7             otherfiles/a.txt  names
Mastrosimone     12             otherfiles/a.txt  names
William      7             otherfiles/a.txt  names
 Tell      4             otherfiles/a.txt  names
Oveture      7             otherfiles/a.txt  names
Gioachino      9             otherfiles/a.txt  names
Rossini      7             otherfiles/a.txt  names
Oklahoma      8             otherfiles/a.txt places
Sydney      6             otherfiles/a.txt places
Dallas      6             otherfiles/a.txt places
Texas      5             otherfiles/a.txt places
  San      3             otherfiles/a.txt places
Fransisco      9             otherfiles/a.txt places
  USA      3             otherfiles/a.txt places
Cupertino      9             otherfiles/a.txt places
Cupertino      9             otherfiles/a.txt places
   CA      2             otherfiles/a.txt places
Vinayak      7             otherfiles/2.txt  names
Sudhindra      9             otherfiles/3.txt  names
Sudhindra      9             otherfiles/3.txt  names
Length = 323 rows
```

Comment: If you want to try with numpy then check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/print-the-full-numpy-array

Answer (score 1):

The `pprint` method allows multiple lines in an astropy Table to be printed without truncation. For example, if `blat` is a Table and you want to print 100 lines:

```
nlines = 100
blat.pprint(nlines)
```

To print all of the lines:

```
nlines = len(blat) + 2
blat.pprint(nlines)
```

where the `+2` is typically needed to account for the header rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Table.pprint_all](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.Table.html#astropy.table.Table.pprint_all) method

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a table and printing each row is an easy way to get around the truncation that Python sometimes applies to long outputs.

Given `t` is a `Table` from `astropy.table`, try this:

```
for row in t:
    print(row.as_void())
```

Here, `row` is a [`Row` object](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.Row.html#astropy.table.Row), and [`as_void()`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.table.Row.html#astropy.table.Row.as_void) produces the raw data for that row.