# How to remove triple dots in iPython console in Spyder?

Tags: ipython, spyder

I am trying to see more details when I run my code.

When I try to print my dataset in my iPython Console, I see the triple dot ellipsis, which hides some of the rows that I want to see.  Is there an option that I can change in the preferences that would allow me to see the full dataset?  Or at least more rows from the dataset?

Comment: `dataset` - are you using `pandas` or `numpy`?  If so, those are more important to producing this ellipsis than the use if Ipython or spyder.

Comment: I imported both the pandas and numpy libraries but I am not using them besides that.

Comment: But are the `...` in display of an array or dataframe?  Those packages have print options.  `ipython` also shows ... as part of the secondary prompt.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/print-the-full-numpy-array