# How do I exhaustively print the values in a 1D Tensor in Tensorflow without getting the truncated output?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a 1D Tensor.

So when I call

```
print(session.run(labels))
```

I get [0, 1, 0 ... , 0 1 0]

It's a list of about 1500 values, how do I print the entire list without writing a loop?

Answer (score 1):

Printing session.run() will output as a numpy array.

You can set the print option as follows:

```
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=numpy.nan)
```

[I found the related answer from this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/print-the-full-numpy-array)