# After vectorize the text the output shown is not full Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, vectorization, tf-idf

I'm dealing with almost 7000 strings and when I vectorize it correctly the output shown the head and the tail of the output

```
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer().fit(tweet_bagow)
tweet_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.transform(tweet_bagow)
print(tweet_tfidf)
```

the output is

```
  (1, 18924)    0.23289785588568357
  (1, 17728)    0.23289785588568357
  (1, 17324)    0.1810217418686322
  (1, 16354)    0.096940817964108
  (1, 15383)    0.22245866652336163
  : :
  (6239, 15381) 0.25658814474406894
  (6239, 13588) 0.28550824143706277
  (6239, 9784)  0.28550824143706277
  (6239, 8280)  0.28550824143706277
  (6239, 6696)  0.22191358948429074
```

how can I print the full output without this ( : : ) thing in the middle?

Comment: What is the `type()` of `tweet_tfidf`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print the full NumPy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/how-to-print-the-full-numpy-array)

Comment: If `tweet_tfidf` were a `float`, printing it would yield a single number, and there wouldn't be any `: :` to get rid of.

Comment: Sorry, this is the type of `tfidf` : `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
` @ScottHunter @DyZ

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#head-a476da892560e3bf994ec9b363e169b6467cd5a4) one has:

*"To disable this behaviour and force NumPy to print the entire array, you can change the printing options using:"*

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold='nan')
```

Comment: I'm not using NumPy on my code, I tried it it is not working. 
Or you can tell me how to implement this and correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: `scikit` uses `numpy`, so you *are* using it, if indirectly.

Comment: but the output of the code is not an array, so it doesn't work.

Comment: @AliYousef then you should operate the options of the type you are getting: if it is a `pandas` dataframe there are corresponding options, if it is a matrix likewise, and so on. As such, first check the type you're outputting and then check the corresponding options for display.

Comment: @gented this is the type of `tfidf` : `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
`