# Unable to Print the Complete Confusion Matrix in Python

Tags: python, deep-learning, prediction, evaluation, confusion-matrix

I am building a image predicting model.

To get the better picture of the accuracy I am printing a confusion matrix using `scikit learn`.

When I was using 30 classes, the confusion matrix was completely displayed in the print screen, but as soon as I use my model on 50 classes, it starts to print truncated/shrinked versions of the confusion matrix.

I tried different ways to print it complete or write it into the file, but it did not work.

The output is something like this:

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
...
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

I also tried `np.set_printoptions`. but it does not work either.

With np.set_printoptions it is not even letting me print anything and I get errors like: `typeError can not implement between int and str`.

Comment: Improved spelling, grammar and formatting.

Comment: Look at a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/how-to-print-the-full-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

You can print complete array without truncating by setting

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
```

or

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)
```

By default arrays larger than 1000 elements will be truncated.

For full documentation, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html.

Comment: Hi Kamil, As I mentioned in the question, its gives me an error or Typecast I guess : typeError can not implement between int and str.

Comment: You cannot not pass str as threshold. It must be int e.g `np.set_printoptions(threshold=5000)`

Comment: Which numpy version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert you array to a list and then print it:

```
my_list = my_array.tolist()
```