# What does ... in an array mean?

Tags: python

I've been manipulating some data and I tried to plot it, with results that didn't make sense.
`dif_fl` is an array with the dimension 4500, and `dif_num` is a float.

```
derivative = dif_fl/dif_num
with open('der.txt', 'w') as fout:
    derivative_str = str(derivative)
    fout.write(derivative_str)
```

The file `der.txt` looks like this:

```
[1.48088146e-38 1.59775424e-38 1.59922651e-38 ... 1.89016384e-16
 1.91981531e-16 1.92202686e-16]
```

This should be another 4500 array, shouldn't it? Is there something, I'm missing?

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/how-to-print-the-full-numpy-array-without-truncation answer your question?

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Wasn't sure what to search for.

Comment: Thank you, it does!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, this happens when there are too many items to be displayed .The ... means that there are more elements that are not shown right now.The only items that are shown are starting and ending items.This doesn't mean that you cannot access these items.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, when I tried to print it in my console. However, I figured, I could save the numbers in a file and review them that way. Is that possible somehow?