# How to print a long output to a file without "..." in the output in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, text-classification

I'm working on a text classification problem via Python. I tried to get the numerical weightage of words using TF-IDF. Here is my code with an example data:

```
from collections import Counter
from tqdm import tqdm
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
import math
import operator
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

corpus = ['this is the first document',
      'this document is the second document',
      'and this is the third one',
      'is this the first document',
]

def IDF(corpus, unique_words):
  idf_dict={}
  N=len(corpus)
  for i in unique_words:
    count=0
    for sen in corpus:
      if i in sen.split():
        count=count+1
      idf_dict[i]=(math.log((1+N)/(count+1)))+1
  return idf_dict

def fit(whole_data):
  # global vocab
  unique_words = set()
  if isinstance(whole_data, (list,)):
    for x in whole_data:
      for y in x.split():
        if len(y)<2:
          continue
        unique_words.add(y)
    unique_words = sorted(list(unique_words))
    vocab = {j:i for i,j in enumerate(unique_words)}
    Idf_values_of_all_unique_words=IDF(whole_data,unique_words)
  return vocab, Idf_values_of_all_unique_words
Vocabulary, idf_of_vocabulary=fit(corpus) 


def transform(dataset,vocabulary,idf_values):
     sparse_matrix= csr_matrix( (len(dataset), len(vocabulary)), dtype=np.float64)
     for row  in range(0,len(dataset)):
       number_of_words_in_sentence=Counter(dataset[row].split())
       for word in dataset[row].split():
           if word in  list(vocabulary.keys()):
               tf_idf_value=(number_of_words_in_sentence[word]/len(dataset[row].split()))*(idf_values[word])
               sparse_matrix[row,vocabulary[word]]=tf_idf_value
    #  print("NORM FORM\n",normalize(sparse_matrix, norm='l2', axis=1, copy=True, return_norm=False))
     output =normalize(sparse_matrix, norm='l2', axis=1, copy=True, return_norm=False)
     return output
final_output=transform(corpus,Vocabulary,idf_of_vocabulary)
```

Up to now, everything is OK. But I want to print the output to a txt file. Here is the code I'm using:

```
with open('satinal22.txt', 'w') as f:
  for i in range(len(corpus)):
    f.write(str(final_output[i].toarray()))
```

For a small data, it gives this output in the file (arrays in the size of 9 numbers):

[[0.         0.46979139 0.58028582 0.38408524 0.         0.
0.38408524 0.         0.38408524]][[0.         0.6876236  0.         0.28108867 0.         0.53864762
0.28108867 0.         0.28108867]][[0.51184851 0.         0.         0.26710379 0.51184851 0.
0.26710379 0.51184851 0.26710379]][[0.         0.46979139 0.58028582 0.38408524 0.         0.
0.38408524 0.         0.38408524]]

However, for large data (3000 number long array), the output is problematic, like:

[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]][[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]][[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]][[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]][[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]][[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]][[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]] (goes on)

How can I print the full output to a txt file without "..."?

Comment: Don't use `str()`.  I'm not sure offhand if the array type you're using has a `repr()` that's suitable, but I'd try that first.  If that doesn't work, write your own loop that will render the array in the format you want it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
import sys
import numpy
numpy.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize)
```

Reference: [How to print the full NumPy array, without truncation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/how-to-print-the-full-numpy-array-without-truncation)