# Write an large array to a text file with specific format (as it is)

Tags: python, numpy

I need to write several NxM arrays generated with numpy to ascii files in the following format:
tab separated values, row per line, no brackets, the dimension of the array (columns rows) in the header.

I have tried something like this:

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.random.random((73,92))
dim = mat.shape

header = "{col}\t{row}\n".format(row = dim[0], col = dim[1])
content = str(mat).replace(' [', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(' ', '\t')

mat_PM  = open('./output_file.dat', "w+")

mat_PM.write(header)
mat_PM.write(content)

mat_PM.close()
```

which returns a file with a summarized array, like this:
[image: output_file.dat]

How do we print the full array?.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Python's str.join() method in order to manually create the content string (instead of using str() on the matrix):

```py
content = "\n".join(["\t".join([str(value) for value in row]) for row in mat])
```

Or the same technique but without using list comprehensions:

```py
row_strings = []
for row in mat:
    values = []
    for value in row:
        values.append(str(value))
    row_strings.append("\t".join(values))
content = "\n".join(row_strings)
```

If instead you want to use numpy's built in string method, you can configure numpy to return the whole array (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987694/how-do-i-print-the-full-numpy-array-without-truncation)):

```py
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf, linewidth=np.inf)
content = str(mat).replace(' [', '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace(' ', '\t')
```

Hope this is useful :)

Comment: at the risk of being self-promotional because the other answer is mine - I've gotta say that you really shouldn't manually write the csv this way. [`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) is much faster, less error prone, and is designed exactly for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy has a function to write arrays to text files with lots of formatting options - see the docs for [`numpy.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and the user guide intro to [saving and loading numpy objects](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/absolute_beginners.html#how-to-save-and-load-numpy-objects).

In your case, something like the following should work:

```py
with open('./output_file.dat', "w+") as mat_PM:
    mat_PM.write(header)
    np.savetxt(mat_PM, mat, fmt="%9f", delimiter="\t")
```